# Modifying colors.css in Drupal?

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

Following the advice of

https://www.drupal.org/node/1117972

I have changed my colors.css to the code at the bottom.  The change is at the bottom of the stylesheet.  However, nothing seems to happen when I save it.

Does Drupal have some sort of cache?  I have checked that I am using the correct theme and the background image does exist.

```
/* ---------- Color Module Styles ----------- */

body,
body.overlay {
  color: #3b3b3b;
}
.comment .comment-arrow {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
#page,
#main-wrapper,
#main-menu-links li a.active,
#main-menu-links li.active-trail a {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tabs ul.primary li a.active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.tabs ul.primary li.active a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#header {
  background-color: #48a9e4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0779bf 0%, #48a9e4 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0779bf 0%, #48a9e4 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0779bf 0%, #48a9e4 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0779bf), color-stop(1, #48a9e4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0779bf 0%, #48a9e4 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0779bf 0%, #48a9e4 100%);
}
a {
  color: #0071B3;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #018fe2;
}
a:active {
  color: #23aeff;
}
.sidebar .block {
  background-color: #f6f6f2;
  border-color: #f9f9f9;
}
#page-wrapper,
#footer-wrapper {
  background: #292929;
}
.region-header,
.region-header a,
.region-header li a.active,
#name-and-slogan,
#name-and-slogan a,
#secondary-menu-links li a {
  color: #fffeff;
}

#page, #main-wrapper {
  background: url(../images/bg.png);
}
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache at Configuration > Development > Performance > Clear all caches.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
```

Also make sure the image is in your `./themes/yourtheme/images`folder

And that the colors.css you are editing is the one inside the `./themes/yourtheme/css` folder (replace 'yourtheme 'with the theme you are using)

Refreshing browser-cache should be enough. (ctrl+f5 on windows, cmd+r on mac)